# Orientation changed event in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, gui, mobile, unity-ui, orientation

I'd like to **listen to orientation change events**, so for example my UI layout or the components themselves can be changed.

All I've found is that I should check the value of `Screen.orientation` **every frame**, and check **if it has changed since previous frame**.

But this isn't really efficient, and I wonder why doesn't Unity provide an **event** for this.

This [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/orientation-manager-75313) seems to have what I need. Anyone knows how is it implemented?

As a last resort I could make a **singleton behaviour** which starts a **coroutine** which checks every X seconds whether it has changed, and if it has, I **fire an event**. But this still seems like a suboptimal solution.

Comment: The asset is probably implemented by checking the Screen.orientation each frame in Update, as you describe. Have you profiled this solution and concluded that it's a significant cost in your application?

Comment: If your UI uses a canvas scaler, it will automatically update when the orientation changes.

Comment: @DMGregory No, I thought that there must be some better solution.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I use canvas scaler but if I design the panel well in horizontal mode, in portrait mode it will so much smaller, like 25% of the original's relative size.